# Visual Studio Express - vb.net code referencing laptop's '\bin\Release' folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compilation, package

I'm a beginner to the VS Express IDE and have been copying my compiled code from my laptop's dev. '\bin\Release' folder directly to my production server.

A production piece of code crashed today and the Exception text makes reference to lines of code in the source .vb file on my laptop's dev. folder (the laptop full folder path revealed this).

I can't figure out how to fully package the application build so the .vb file is referenced locally on the server and not the original version during the compile.

Do I simply set the .vb file property 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'copy always'?

Comment: Those bin folders are Visual Studio folders, they dont typically exist in production and even if they did, depending on deployment you may not have access to them.

Comment: Consider a deployment mechanism, e.g. [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) for basic setup tasks

Comment: `Do I simply set the .vb file property 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'copy always'?` - **NO!** Code is not referenced in non-compiled form. The error message refers to _**where**_ in the source code _**the error was thrown**_, not the actual code itself. Please post the error message, stack trace, the source code that the error refers to, and other information that could be useful.